How To Automatically Unhide All Rows, Unhide All Columns, Disable and Enable Filters Using Google Script
Good morning. I am trying to create a google script in excel that will do these steps below automatically:
1st Step: It will unhide all rows.
2nd Step: It will unhide all columns.
3rd and Final Step: It will disable and then enable the filter from Cell B1:D1.
I also want to use Cell A2 as a reference in which will be the last column that I am going to apply the filter.
I am using this script below but it does not work. Please help.
function RunFinal() {
  
  const sheetName = "Sheet21";
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);

  const col = sheet.getRange("A2").getValue();
  const colrange = sheet.getRange("B1:" + col + "1");

  sheet.colrange.activate();
  sheet.getActiveSheet().getFilter().remove();
  sheet.colrange.activate();
  sheet.colrange.createFilter();

}



Suggestion:
You can try these modifications from your existing script
Script:
function runFinal() {

  const sheetName = "Sheet21";
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);

  const lastColumn = sheet.getRange("A2").getValue();
  //Unhide all rows
  sheet.showRows(1, sheet.getMaxRows());

  //Unhide all columns
  sheet.showColumns(1, sheet.getMaxColumns());

  // disable and then enable the filter from Cell B1:D1.
  var range = sheet.getRange("B1:D1");
  var filter = range.getFilter();

  // Disable filter
  if (filter !== null) {
    filter.remove();
  }

  // Enable filter
  sheet.getRange("B1:" + lastColumn + "1").createFilter();
}

Output:


References:
showRows
showColumns
createFilter
